# Script works in IDLE but not in cmd - codec error

Tags: python, cmd, scheduler, python-idle

I have a script that works in IDLE but not when I run the same script in cmd. Then I get this error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 12, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 17: character maps 
to <undefined>
```

The error occurs when I try to print a string that contains the following part " - ". When the script is run in IDLE everything works perfectly. I use Python 2.7 on Windows 7 and I would like to use the Windows Scheduler to schedule the script and as I understand the it the script is then executed in cmd. Two questions:

1. Why do I get this different results dependent on where the script is executed and what do I need to do to fix it?
2. Is it possible to start the "Python (Command Line)" to run the script from the Windows Scheduler as a workaround?

Comment: Could you post the script or relevant parts?

Comment: I use Beautiful Soup to extract values from a web page, nothing strange.  This is the code: txtStrip = tds[n].text.strip() print txtStrip

Comment: This is the address: http://cust.msse.se/se/skandia/quickrank/default.aspx?clientattributes=8&account=0 and it is Skandia European – General Electric that creates the error.

Comment: I believe that IDLE encodes the utf strings, whereas the CMD does not. What ever string you are trying to use/resolve try this `u'whatever \u2013'`. It should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I/O in Python (and most other languages) is based on bytes. When you write a byte string (str in 2.x, bytes in 3.x) to a file, the bytes are simply written as-is. When you write a Unicode string (unicode in 2.x, str in 3.x) to a file, the data needs to be encoded to a byte sequence. To see further explication see [Dive into Python 3 chapter on strings](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/strings.html). 
Try this using the unicode string:

for example:

```
>>> print(u'\u2013')
–
```

whereas:

```
>>> print("\u2013")
\u2013
```